# nvidia Screen tearing on Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: xubuntu, 18.04, tearing, nvidia-settings

I have tried this settings but no changes:

```
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

How to solve this screen tearing issue?

Graphics: Nvidia GTX 960m

```
$ lspci -nnk | awk -v n='[0300]' 'p&&/^\S/{p=0}!p{p=index($0,n)}p'

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 [8086:191b] (rev 06)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. HD Graphics 530 [1043:1c5d]
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915

$ xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
1600x1024     60.17  
1400x1050     59.98  
1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
1280x1024     60.02  
1440x900      59.89  
1400x900      59.96    59.88  
1280x960      60.00  
1440x810      60.00    59.97  
1368x768      59.88    59.85  
1360x768      59.80    59.96  
1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
1152x864      60.00  
1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
1024x768      60.04    60.00  
960x720       60.00  
928x696       60.05  
896x672       60.01  
1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
960x600       59.93    60.00  
960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
840x525       60.01    59.88  
864x486       59.92    59.57  
800x512       60.17  
700x525       59.98  
800x450       59.95    59.82  
640x512       60.02  
720x450       59.89  
700x450       59.96    59.88  
640x480       60.00    59.94  
720x405       59.51    58.99  
684x384       59.88    59.85  
680x384       59.80    59.96  
640x400       59.88    59.98  
576x432       60.06  
640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
512x384       60.00  
512x288       60.00    59.92  
480x270       59.63    59.82  
400x300       60.32    56.34  
432x243       59.92    59.57  
320x240       60.05  
360x202       59.51    59.13  
320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lspci -nnk | awk -v n='[0300]' 'p&&/^\S/{p=0}!p{p=index($0,n)}p'`, `dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package} ${Version} nvidia-\* | sed -ne 's/^i //'` and `xrandr`? Thanks.

Comment: `dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package} ${Version} nvidia-\* | sed -ne 's/^i //'` this line expects ending.

Comment: `dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package} ${Version}' nvidia-\* | sed -ne 's/^i //'` this lines doesn't output anything.

Comment: Dang it, another missing character! I tested the command more thoroughly: `dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package} ${Version}\n' nvidia-\* | sed -ne 's/^i //p'`. Sorry for the confusion and delay.